# Why does adding a single class to the htb qdisc in tc slow down my connection?

Tags: linux, linux-networking, tc

I'm running tc with the command:

`sudo tc qdisc add dev eth0 root handle 1: htb default 1`.

I then proceed to add a single class like so:

`sudo tc class add dev eth0 parent 1:0 classid 1:1 htb rate 100% prio 0`

My understanding is that, since class with minor ID 1 is set as the default, all packets will be enqueued at this class. Since this class is allowed all of the bandwidth, there should be no slowdown. Yet, as soon as I type this command my SSH connections slows to a several-second response time.

What's wrong with my understanding?

Comment: my version of tc (iproute2-ss190107) refuses a rate percent as valid syntax. Perhaps yours ignored it, giving a rate of 100 bits/s or something similar

Comment: @A.B you're completely correct; that's the problem. It's a bummer that this syntax is described in the man page then (and that it fails silently).